# Which data stores are supported by Open Day Light (ODL)

Tags: datastore, sdn, opendaylight

Does Open Day Light (ODL) support any third party datastores for storing MD-SAL South Bound and North Bound Model Data? If not, then is it a proprietary data store that they use?

Tried to search few ODL related docs but could not get answer to the above question. Any pointer to the documentation would also help.

Answer (score 1):

ODL uses xml based database which is MD-SAL.
MD-SAL consists of two data stores, config and operational. There is no third party database support as of now in ODL.
Data is arranged in tree structure in MD SAL.

Comment: Thanks. Is it an in-memory data store?

Comment: Yes , it is in memory data store.

Comment: Thanks. Is this in-memory datastore a ODL proprietary one or a 3rd party one like infinispan?